# Intellij reports dependency error when it actually has no errors

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using a deeplearning4j dependency in my project, and this library does occur in the External Dependencies tree, but there is red flag in my code.

When I run the application in IntelliJ, it has no issue at all. `mvn clean install` doesn't generate any issue either. The only issue is the annoying red flag error. Please see the attachment. I tried all tests, but still can't get rid of the message. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"? Is deeplearning4j  library added to module dependencies in "Project Structure 
 Modules - Dependencies"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
I closed the project and imported it from the pom file. 
That worked for me!